# Не проигрываются анимации на Unity при создании 2D проекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Столкнулся с проблемой во время прописывания анимаций для персонажа. При нажатии на  клавиши движения срабатывает лишь 1 из всех имеющихся анимаций (та которая была прикреплена первой), однако в случае, если каждую анимацию соединить между собой, проигрываются все подряд (юзал в качестве проверки на работоспособность самих файлов с анимациями).

[[image: Аниматор]

[image: Код для проигрывания таковых]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты не читал документацию.
Нужно выстроить State Machine из анимаций,а каждому переходу задать условие(каждому разное)

```
const int RUN_LEFT = 1;
...
if(Input.GetKey("a"){
  anim.setInteger("run_left", RUN_LEFT);
}
else if(Input.GetKey("b"){
...
}
```

не забудь настроить эти переходы и задать условия выхода из анимации.

Comment: Спасибо, виноват, не прочёл.